# War not being deployed to Tomcat

Tags: reactjs, spring, tomcat, war

I've created a Spring Boot / React application - all code is stored in the same war file. If I run it in intelliJ (mvn spring-boot:run) all works fine http://localhost:8080/myapp displays my react front-end which calls back to my Spring backend.  Now if I copy the war file to the webapps folder in tomcat, doing localhost:8080/myapp displays nothing - I thought my react front end would appear but just a blank page?  I guess I'm doing something wrong, any ideas?  I have war as package in pom file and tomcat as provided, I also override configure:

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ReturnsdashboardApplication.class);
    }

}
```

****UPDATE****
I have noticed that when the app is built, the index.html page is adding a / at the start of any links.  For example:

```
<link href="/static/css/main.8c8b27cf.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

If I remove the / it then picks up my application context as part of the url and works.  Not sure why it is adding the / when being built?

Thanks

Comment: You could check if you can run the war file with. java -jar myapp.war. If that works fine the war file should be ok. Does the tomcat use the correct java version ? Is the app deployed (war file extracted) in the tomcat ?

Comment: java -jar myapp.war didn't work - got ClassNotFoundException - didn't know you could run a war that way? Tomcat on same version as the app, app is deployed fine.  In webapps folder I have myapp.war and then a folder myapp which has the WEB-INF and META-INF folder in there.  When I go to chrome developer tools, I get a 404:  GET http://localhost:8080/static/css/main.8c8b27cf.chunk.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404   Not sure why my application context is not in the GET request?

Comment: I can access my backend end point no problem: http://localhost:8080/returnsdashboard/api/home  but localhost:8080/returnsdashboard should show my react front end as it does when I run my app in intelliJ.

Comment: you should be able to run a spring boot .war as jar, that does not count for all .war's.

Have you bundles all your static sources in to the .war? Are you sure your static resource are served correctly ? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources

Comment: For some reason, the index.html file which gets built adds a / on all the links?  For example: <script src="/static/js/2.507eac03.chunk.js"> should be <script src="static/js/2.507eac03.chunk.js">  so no start slash, if I do this manually it works - not sure why npm run build would do this as it means it is not picking up my application context.